# ios programmatic UI versus autolayout best practices

Tags: ios, user-interface, autolayout, pixel

I'm trying to understand the best practices on layout out UI in ios. Specifically, I'm try to understand the advantages / disadvantages between: pure programmatic UI, Storyboarding and XIBs, and auto-layout in ios 6.0+.

I'm used to pure programmatic UI (no auto-layout) but I'm trying to understand where I could potentially have problems. Are fractional coordinates a problem? Would I have to deal with a lot of conditionals to deal with different ios screen sizes or could I just take care of that in code with percentages.

I've seen a few threads on this on stackoverflow but nothing comprehensive enough.

Comment: It all depends on YOU. I'm more comfortable with pro grammatical app roach because its much easier to modify if you've commented out your code. UI however gives you a better live layout.

Comment: http://codewithchris.com/xcode-using-storyboards-and-xibs-versus-creating-views-programmatically/ From a technical point there seem to be no disadvantages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The end product is the same regardless of if you've added the constraints in code or in interface builder. You don't have to deal with fractional coordinates or, in most cases, different screen sizes - that's pretty much the *point* of Autolayout.

In Xcode 4, editing constraints in interface builder was terrible. It's much improved in Xcode 5. However, if you're used to generating your UI in code, then I'd recommend carrying on the same way as you transition to Autolayout.

If you're interested I have written a series of [blog posts](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/13/autolayout/) on Autolayout, covering interface builder, visual format language, individual creation of constraints and [my Autolayout helper category](https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout) greatly simplifies building layouts in code.

Comment: thanks for your thoughtful reply. Question -- do you think it's bad form to programmatically layout my UI without using autolayout? I want to understand whether you think it's better form to use autolayout. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know if "form" comes into it. I find Autolayout much easier than setting frames but then I've spent a _long_ time with it. Sometimes manual frames are right, usually Autolayout wins. By default I'd use Autolayout.

Comment: I just published an article ["30 Auto Layout Best Practices"](http://blog.supereasyapps.com/30-auto-layout-best-practices/) that covers a lot of the strategies I use when adding constraints (which apply to both code and Storyboards). Xcode 9 is much easier to use with Auto Layout than previous versions.